# Term driven pages not working when term is more than one word

Tags: 2013, content-query-web-part, enterprise-wiki, term

I am using term driven pages in my Enterprise wiki site and have connected the target page. In the page template I am using the Content Search web part to display items in the wiki site that use the wiki category. (e.g. user goes to Deployment page and only items with the wiki category deployment are displayed.)

Here's the search I'm using in the Content Search web part.

*path:"https://examplesite.com/ls/knowledgebase/Pages"  (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem") WikiCategory:{URLTOKEN.1}*

All seems to be working fine except when the wiki category is more than one word (e.g. Industry reports). In this case the URL is "industry-reports" and SharePoint is not able to translate that to the wiki category "industry reports" and populate the Content Search web part.

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Is there a better way to do this? Any help is appreciated.